# Is a new array copied or pointer to array referenced in struct?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

struct Pixels {
    const uint16_t *bitmap;
};

struct Animation {
    //uint16_t *frames;
    const Pixels *frames;
};



static const uint16_t array2d[2][16] = {
    {
        0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1,
        0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1,
        0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1,
        0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1
    }, {
        0x6, 0x9, 0x1, 0x5,
        0x6, 0x9, 0x1, 0x1,
        0x6, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1,
        0x6, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1
    }
};

//static Pixels combined[] = {frame0, frame1};
static const Pixels combined[] = {array2d[0], array2d[1]};

const Animation spoon {
  combined
  //new Pixels[2]{array2d[0], array2d[1]}

};

int main()
{
    // need to access frames
    const Pixels *ptr = spoon.frames;

    for (unsigned int f=0; f<2; f++) {

        for (unsigned int p=0; p<16; p++) {
            std::cout << ptr[f].bitmap[p] << "\n";

        }

    }
}
```

If i create 500 more Animation structs and call each spoon1, spoon2 ... spoon500 (like the original spoon), will this take up an absurd amount of memory if array2d is directly copied to each spoon, or is only the pointer referenced (instead of an entirely new 2x16 duplicate of `array2d[][]`, or new `combined[]`)?

Generally speaking, If I create many variables (`spoon1`...`spoon500`) with the same `combined` variable:

```
const Animation spoon1... {
  combined
};
```

do all the `spoon...` refer to combined without making duplicates?

Comment: how would you copy it? It dont see how the code is related to the question, you neither copy an `Animation` nor a 2d array...

Comment: const Animation spoon1 {
  combined
};
const Animation spoon2 {
  combined
};
// ...
I plan on creating a bunch of spoon structs (which will soon be sprites), so would the contents of combined that are put into the newly created spoon be copied instead of acting as a reference? 
I don't know how to phrase it any better, but is array2d duplicated into combined and then into each spoon that is created (thus using a lot more memory per spoon created)?

Comment: I'm native to Java so all this pointer stuff is new to me, so In better wording: "If I create many spoon objects, will each refer to or create a copy of `array2d`". Will `combined` be copied or referred to also?

Comment: Java is all pointers.  Although in Java terminology, they call them _references_, except where the abstraction leaked out, like in `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Comment: you dont need "all this pointer suff",see answer

Comment: creating 500 variables called `spoon1`, `spoon2` etc. is generally a bad idea, you should use some container

Comment: The animations are better to be separate variables or mapped in like a HashMap (but c++ I dont think has that. Each animation will belong to a certain sprite). Animations will never be modified, just read from. What type of container should I use for a const `Animation`?

Answer (score 0):

`Animation` has only a pointer as member. Arrays are not pointers. When you have a pointer to the first element of an array and copy it, then the copy will point to the same array. Better use `std::array`, for example for a 3x2 member array:

```
#include <array>
struct Foo {
    std::array<std::array<int,2>,3> data{1,2,
                                         3,4,
                                         5,6};
};

int main(){
    Foo f;
    Foo f2 = f;
}
```

If you want to have 500 more Animations, you should not create variables named `spoon1`,`spoon2`, etc, but instead use a `std::array<Animation,500>`.

Comment: For the program I'm going to make, animations will never change, so they will be defined at start and be const (I think). These animations will be part of a `Sprite` struct, which will basically be a character, item, or enemy in a game (so there can be multiple sprites referring to the same animations, so there is no need to copy).
Would `std::array` still be useful in this scenario? The platform that this program will be used on has limited resources, so I'm trying to use as little memory as possible.

Comment: "so there is no need to copy" I am a bit confused. I thought the question is about copying a 2d array. If you dont want copies, then simply dont copy the array ;) yes `std::array` is still what you should prefer to c-style arrays

Comment: You don't need an `std::array` to have the array copied with the rest of the struct by the default copy constructor/assignment. A standard C array will do as well.

Comment: Seems to be literally the opposite of what the OP's after!

Answer (score 0):

> do all the spoon... refer to combined without making duplicates?

Yes.

Each one has a single pointer to the same array (or, rather, a pointer to the first element in that array).

It's a bit confusing because when you use the term `combined` in an expression like this, it's automatically converted from being "an array", to "a pointer to the first element of this array", even though the two things are not the same. That's unfortunate but we inherited it from C.

I admit that it does *look like* a value copy of the thing being named, i.e. the array `combined`. But, it's not.

Note that it's really only the names of arrays and the names of functions (a story for another day) that have this oddity. *Usually*, passing a name of a thing like this will involve a copy by default, because C++ has value semantics, not reference semantics like Java.

Anyway, once you realise that you're just storing lots of pointers to the same array, the concern goes away.

So:

> will this take up an absurd amount of memory

No.

> I'm native to Java so all this pointer stuff is new to me, so In better wording: "If I create many spoon objects, will each refer to or create a copy of array2d". Will combined be copied *[..]* also?

No.